# Trying to pass variable value to another variable(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

Im trying to pass a value from a ng-repeat variable to another variable in angularjs using ng-click. Im doing this so i can change the src of my iframe.
Anyhow here is a snippet of my code.

NG-REPEAT

```
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:filterText">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedmodal" ng-click="feedurl='{{feed.link | removehttp | removehttp2}}">{{feed.title}}</a>

        </li>
```

IFRAME

```
                    <iframe id='ifr' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="550" height="400" ng-src="{{feedurl}}"></iframe>
```

Any help would be appreciated. And maybe i will send you a cookie jar:)

Have a nice day!

Comment: `ngClick` doesnt need the `{{}}` and it can't use filters like that. Use a function in the `ngClick` - do the logic in the controller, then assign to `feedurl`

Comment: @tymeJV Thank you that solved my issue. You get a cookie